# Want to terminate the program after giving the answer

Tags: python-2.7

I am Working on this BMI calculator code but when I run the program and enter all the values it gives the answer but keeps on repeating. I want that the program terminates after giving the answer.
**I also want the answer to be in decimals.**

here is the code:-

```
import math
print "*After Entering Every value Hit Enter"
time.sleep(2)

#intro Starts
name = raw_input("Please Enter Your Name : ") #enter your name
print""
print "Hello", name
time.sleep(0.5)
print""
print "It Feels Like Your Are Really Concerned About Your Health"
time.sleep(3)
print "So Lets Start Calculating Your BMI"
print "" #intro ends

#option for gender
gender = raw_input('Are you Male Or female ? ')
print "OK, Thats great"
print ""
#the bmi Calculation
kg = float(input('Enter Your Weight(in Kg.) : '))
cm = float(input('Enter Your height(in cm)  : '))
print "" 
meter = cm * math.pow(10, -2)
bmi = float(kg//(meter**2))

#the Conditions start
while gender == "male":
     if bmi < 18.5: #if overweight
        print "It seems like your are Underweight"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print ("")
        print "I prefer you To Increase Your diet."
    #if normal
    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 25:
        print "Your are Absolutely fine"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "Be on the same track"
    #if overweight
    elif bmi > 25 and bmi <=30:
        print "Your are overweight "
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to go for daily morning Jog."
    #if obese
    elif bmi > 30:
        print "Your are under obese category"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to Change your diet"
while gender == "female" or "Female" :
   print "sorry this program is under development"
print ("")
```

I will be thankful if somebody helps me.
I am A begineer

Comment: If the loop needs be run only once, try `if` instead of `while`

Comment: And `gender == "female" or "Female"` should be replaced with `gender in ("female", "Female")`. Otherwise, the condition always evaluates to `True`, since a non-empty string is truthy in Python.

Comment: Check the new edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use break command to break your loop:

```
while gender == "male":
     if bmi < 18.5: #if overweight
        print "It seems like your are Underweight"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print ("")
        print "I prefer you To Increase Your diet."
    #if normal
    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 25:
        print "Your are Absolutely fine"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
    break
```

Also , don't forget to add wait at the end of your loop so your program don't exit immediately after finishing:

```
import time
time.sleep(100)
```

### Edit:

You edited the code so I also edited and improved your code:

```
while gender == "male":
     if bmi < 18.5: #if overweight
        print "It seems like your are Underweight"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print ("")
        print "I prefer you To Increase Your diet."
    #if normal
    elif bmi <= 25:
        print "Your are Absolutely fine"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "Be on the same track"
    #if overweight
    elif bmi <=30:
        print "Your are overweight "
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to go for daily morning Jog."
    #if obese
    elif bmi > 30:
        print "Your are under obese category"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to Change your diet"
    break
while gender.lower() == "female":
   print "sorry this program is under development"
print ("")
```

## Edit2:

I just tried running your program. Your code has a lot of mistakes and bugs. You are not importing `time` whereas you are using it to wait. `\n` means newline. Rather than writing `print ""` you can simply write `\n` where you want a new line in your old `print` statement. If we write `Male` in the gender , then the conditions will not run. Try the following:

```
import math,time
print "*After Entering Every value Hit Enter"
time.sleep(2)

#intro Starts
name = raw_input("Please Enter Your Name : ") #enter your name
print "\nHello\n", name
time.sleep(0.5)
print "It Feels Like Your Are Really Concerned About Your Health"
time.sleep(3)
print "So Lets Start Calculating Your BMI\n"

#option for gender
gender = raw_input('Are you Male Or female ? ')
gender = gender.lower()
if gender != "male" and gender != "female":
    print "Invalid Gender"
    time.sleep(10)
    quit()
print "OK, Thats great\n"
#the bmi Calculation
kg = float(input('Enter Your Weight(in Kg) : '))
cm = float(input('Enter Your height(in cm) : '))
print "" 
meter = cm * math.pow(10, -2)
bmi = float(kg//(meter**2))

#the Conditions start
while gender == "male":
    if bmi < 18.5: #if overweight
        print "It seems like your are Underweight\nYour BMI is\n", bmi,"\nI prefer you To Increase Your diet."
    elif bmi < 25:
        print "Your are Absolutely fine\nYour BMI is", bmi,"\nBe on the same track\n"
    elif bmi <=30 :
        print "Your are overweight \nYour BMI is", bmi,"\nI prefer you to go for daily morning Jog."
    elif bmi > 30:
        print "Your are under obese category\nYour BMI is", bmi,"\nI prefer you to Change your diet"
    break
while gender == "female":
   print "Sorry! this program is under development"
   break
print ("")
```

Comment: Just using `if` instead of `while` would be easier and would require less typing. If using `while` and `break` is desired, it might be better to put a single `break` after the last `elif` inside the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

So you should try considering `if` instead of `while` if you don't want to repeat the process

```
import math
import time
print "*After Entering Every value Hit Enter"
time.sleep(2)

#intro Starts
name = raw_input("Please Enter Your Name : ") #enter your name
print""
print "Hello", name
time.sleep(0.5)
print""
print "It Feels Like Your Are Really Concerned About Your Health"
time.sleep(3)
print "So Lets Start Calculating Your BMI"
print "" #intro ends

#option for gender
gender = raw_input('Are you Male Or female ? ')
print "OK, Thats great"
print ""
#the bmi Calculation
kg = float(input('Enter Your Weight(in Kg.) : '))
cm = float(input('Enter Your height(in cm)  : '))
print "" 
meter = cm * math.pow(10, -2)
bmi = float(kg//(meter**2))

#the Conditions start
if gender == "male":
    if bmi < 18.5: #if overweight
        print "It seems like your are Underweight"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print ("")
        print "I prefer you To Increase Your diet."

    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 25:
        print "Your are Absolutely fine"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "Be on the same track"
    #if overweight
    elif bmi > 25 and bmi <=30:
        print "Your are overweight "
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to go for daily morning Jog."
    #if obese
    elif bmi > 30:
        print "Your are under obese category"
        print "Your BMI is", bmi
        print "I prefer you to Change your diet"
if gender in ("female" ,"Female" ):  #gender == "female" or "Female"  is always true
print "sorry this program is under development"
print ("")
```

Comment: What if he/she wants to use `while` for some reason and he has just given us a sample?

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question  and the he problem he faced was that `but keeps on repeating` . And as I said ` if you don't want to repeat the process` you could use `if`. It was a suggestion